# How to pass form data to event subscriber on submit

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I need to get the chosen brand for the MetaSubscriber `getUrl` callback. This function generates a URL like `/brand-model` based on the brand that gets passed to the function and the `baseFieldName` that's chosen in the metasubscriber (in this case being model).

This currently gives me the previous brand on updating and `null` on creating a new entry.

## My question

Is there any way I can pass the submitted Brand to the `getUrl` function to generate my URLs?

## My code

This is the MetaSubscriber in my Formbuilder, which calls the `getUrl` function to generate a URL for the added entry.

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(
            new AddMetaSubscriber(
                'Glasses',
                'GlassesDetail',
                GlassesRepository::class,
                'getUrl',
                [
                    'getData.getId',
                    'getData.getBrand' //Need to get the submitted brand here

                    //I've tried with `brand` like it works for the model but I get an "Undefined method" error

                ],
                'model'
            )
        );
```

Which gets the URL from the following function:

```
public function getUrl(string $url, int $id = null, string $brand = null): string
    {
        $query = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->select('COUNT(i)')
            ->innerJoin('i.meta', 'm')
            ->where('m.url = :url')
            ->setParameter('url', $url);

        if ($id !== null) {
            $query
                ->andWhere('i.id != :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id);
        }
        $url = strtolower($brand)."-".$url;

        if ((int)$query->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult() === 0) {
            return $url;
        }

        return $this->getUrl(Model::addNumber($url), $id, $brand);
    }
```

**AddMetaSubscriber class**

```
<?php

namespace Backend\Form\EventListener;

use Backend\Core\Engine\Model;
use Backend\Form\Type\MetaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Use this class to add meta url generating to your symfony form.
 *
 * Example: $builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddMetaSubscriber(...));
 */
class AddMetaSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string - The URL shown in the backend will need this "action" to be generated.
     */
    private $actionForUrl;

    /**
     * @var string - The field in the form where the URL should be generated for.
     */
    private $baseFieldName;

    /**
     * @var string - Name of the class or the container service id, f.e.: 'moduleForUrl.repository.item',
     */
    private $generateUrlCallbackClass;

    /**
     * @var string - Name of the public method which returns you the URL, f.e.: "getUrl"
     */
    private $generateUrlCallbackMethod;

    /**
     * @var array - Extra parameters you want to include in the AJAX call to get the URL, f.e.: ["getData.getLocale", "getForm.getParent.getParent.getData.getMenuEntityId"]
     */
    private $generateUrlCallbackParameterMethods;

    /**
     * @var string - The URL shown in the backend will need this "module" to be generated.
     */
    private $moduleForUrl;

    public function __construct(
        string $moduleForUrl,
        string $actionForUrl,
        string $generateUrlCallbackClass,
        string $generateUrlCallbackMethod,
        array $generateUrlCallbackParameterMethods,
        string $baseFieldName = 'title'
    ) {
        $this->moduleForUrl = $moduleForUrl;
        $this->actionForUrl = $actionForUrl;
        $this->generateUrlCallbackClass = $generateUrlCallbackClass;
        $this->generateUrlCallbackMethod = $generateUrlCallbackMethod;
        $this->generateUrlCallbackParameterMethods = $generateUrlCallbackParameterMethods;
        $this->baseFieldName = $baseFieldName;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getForm()->add(
            'meta',
            MetaType::class,
            [
                'base_field_name' => $this->baseFieldName,
                'detail_url' => Model::getUrlForBlock($this->moduleForUrl, $this->actionForUrl),
                'generate_url_callback_class' => $this->generateUrlCallbackClass,
                'generate_url_callback_method' => $this->generateUrlCallbackMethod,
                'generate_url_callback_parameters' => $this->buildCallbackParameters($event),
            ]
        );
    }

    private function buildCallbackParameters(FormEvent $event): array
    {
        $parameters = [];

        foreach ($this->generateUrlCallbackParameterMethods as $generateUrlCallbackParameterMethod) {
            $parameter = $event;
            $methods = explode('.', $generateUrlCallbackParameterMethod);

            foreach ($methods as $method) {
                $parameter = $parameter->{$method}();
            }

            $parameters[] = $parameter;
        }

        return $parameters;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is always a trade off between posting too much code and not enough.  I think your question is squarely in the land of too much.  Might consider trying to narrow it down.  Especially since you seem to using a highly customized version of the Symfony framework.  Or perhaps your own.  I think you are asking about an issue related to form events? I get lost after that.

Comment: I added all the files that get used for my problem since last time I got downvoted for not including enough code. I guess I'll remove it again then..
I've stated my question at the top: How can I pass the brand (chosen in a form) to the `getUrl` function.

Comment: @Alessandro I suggest taking a good look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html and defining a function that just calls `getUrl`? Also take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php if you have trouble adding stuff from the parent scope... (like options)

Comment: @Jakumi it's not really an option to change everything since the MetaSubscriber generates everything like page title, meta keywords, meta description, ... which I need. I just need to be able to pass the selected brand. I'll include the `AddMetaSubscriber` class if that helps explain it.

Comment: your buildCallbackParameters reminds me so much of the symfony PropertyAccessor, however. I assume you get an error message? care to post that?

Comment: I don't really get an error, the brand is just empty on create and uses the previously selected brand on update.

Comment: you are aware, that PRE_SET_DATA uses the data that is already present and not the data that is submit by the form? ;o) try PRE_SUBMIT_DATA (i believe) .. and probably additionally ... or something ...

Comment: Upon reading the links you provided earlier I have noticed that and tried with `PRE_SUBMIT` but then I get the following error: _Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(378) : eval()'d code on line 67_